# How to securely make an API call to a backend using GitHub Actions and a secret token?

Tags: rest, security, github-actions, github-api

I am creating a GitHub action that I want to distribute for others to use. However, I don't want others to see the logic of the code, and I also don't want them to be able to read a secret token that the code is using. I made the repository private, but I read that users can still get information from it via logs. I am therefore wondering how to best set this up.

Regarding the first concern, can people see the actual code or only prints to the logs if the repo is private? How about API calls, will they see that traffic (assuming I am not printing it)?

Regarding the second concern, I put the token in a file in the repo, but I know that is not safe. I also tried to set it as a repo-secret, but I was unable to find out how to use it.

I thought that I might need to set up another server with all the code and only trigger it with the action. This can be done because the user of the action is passing an authentication token to the action via secrets, so I can use that to authenticate with my external server. I also saw that GitHub Apps exist, but I could not figure out if they were the solution I was looking for.

Can anyone provide advice on how to set this up? I would be incredibly thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Users of your GitHub action can read the code unless you distribute it as a [Docker action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action) with some compiled binary of your code, however, this can be still reverse engineered as your users will have your action.

So having your secrets baked-in your action is generally a bad idea.

You can just have your "hidden logic and secrets" in a hosted application and then use your GitHub action to run it.